# Azure Functions with Consumption plan - create a task and return

Tags: azure-functions

I need to create a async task, but not wait for it before return. Is it supported with consumption plan?

The reason I ask is because the func app will time out after a period of time once the func returns. But my async task is still running...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Mark and Boris! However, we cannot change current design. Will azure functions app service plan work?

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern for this would be to use another function to perform the async task. For example, if your function is HTTP triggered and needs to return a prompt response but also execute a background task, you could add the task to a queue that triggers a separate worker function.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-3-async-http-apis) for this. This also lets you monitor the async task.